# Can't send logout request to Identity Server from MVC application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, owin, identityserver4, identity

in my application I accept owin authentication towards Identity Server. Everything works well, except the logout part. In practice when I want to logout I expect to be logged out also from my Identity server but this doesn't happen and I logout only from my application. The code is the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login.aspx")
});

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

var AuthorityUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorityUrl"];

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = AuthorityUrl,
    RedirectUri = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortalWebUrl"]}/signin-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortalWebUrl"]}/signout-callback-oidc",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ClientId = "portal-local",
    AuthenticationType = "oidc",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ResponseType = "id_token token",
    Scope = "openid profile email",
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
        {
            var claimsToExclude = new[]
            {
                "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
            };

            var claimsToKeep = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Where(x => !claimsToExclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();

            claimsToKeep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

            var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role");
            ci.AddClaims(claimsToKeep);

            n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
        {
            if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
            {
                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
});
```

the "warning" coming back from Identity Server is the following:

[image]

Can you help me figuring out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make the end session request yourself (not using any middleware to do it for you)? It says invalid http method so what http method did you choose to make your request?

Comment: @Randy yes.. and the problem was that the post_back from the button (talking about WebForms here) was not giving the correct result. The middleware to work properly needs a total redirect to a "logout" page, that at initialization triggers indeed the behavior of the middleware. If you try to trigger this logic through a button and post back it does not work.. I think it's an incompatibility between Identity Server 4 and old Web Forms applications